# SQL: combine student records to reflect the latest

Tags: sql

so I have the following table:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| studentId | deptId  | level     | startDate    | passDate   |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | Math1   | Freshman  | 01-01-2014   | 01-01-2015 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 2         | Eng1    | Feshman   | 01-01-2012   | 01-01-2013 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | Math1   | Sophomore | 01-01-2015   | 01-01-2016 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | Math1   | Junior    | 01-01-2016   | 01-01-2017 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 1         | Math1   | Senior    | 01-01-2017   | 05-05-2017 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 2         | Eng1    | Sophomore | 01-01-2013   | 01-01-2013 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 2         | Eng1    | Junior    | 01-01-2014   | null       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

`studentId` - The students ID

`deptId` - The students department Id

`level` - The standing level of the student

`start` - The date at which the student began the standing

`passDate` - the date at which the student graduated from that standing

I want to combine the rows based on the passDate so that the records are rolled into the latest date. I also want to update the startDate to the earliest standing date. `null` means that the student still hasn't graduated from that standing. So after merging the table above, I expect something like this:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| studentId | deptId | level  | startDate  | passDate   |
+-----------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Math1  | Senior | 01-01-2014 | 05-05-2017 |
+-----------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| 2         | Eng1   | Junior | 01-01-2014 | null       |
+-----------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please only tag one database being used. i removed multiple tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT studentId, deptId, level, MIN(startDate) AS startDate, passDate 
FROM (SELECT * FROM your_table
      ORDER BY studentId, startDate DESC) t
GROUP BY studentId;
```

First, in the subquery, you order the table so that the first row for each student is the one with the latest date. Now, if you select this subquery and group by `studentId`, you end up with the first rows for each student (that is, the latest records). To update `startDate` to the earliest standing date, you select the minimum date of each group.

You can try the query with your data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/836b72/6

**Edit:** here is another query that works both with [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/836b72/7) and [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb9b6e/1):

```
SELECT Table1.studentId, deptId, level, minDate AS startDate, passDate 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT studentId, MAX(startDate) AS maxDate, MIN(startDate) AS minDate 
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY studentId) t ON Table1.startDate = t.maxDate AND Table1.studentId = t.studentId;
```

Comment: This will generate errors on SQL Server, and probably on some other databases as well. The only database I know that will accept this as valid sql is MySql.

Comment: You are right, I was wrongly assuming it was about MySQL. I edited the answer to add a valid SQL Server query.